# How to make local apache server public/visible?

Tags: apache-2.2, fedora

I am running an Apache2 server on a Fedora 13. I'd like to make it publicly accessible(visible).For example I'd like when somebody types http://my.ip.numbes/ that they would see what I have in my document root folder. Just for a presentation of a course work at university.

Permissions are set to 755. User owning the document root is apache. SELinux is temporarily disabled. But port 80 is closed. I tried to open it by adding an entry to iptables and restarting them, no change. I guess I am missing something big here.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I have a static (public, real) IP address.

Question added: If it is a ISP issue, can I make Apache listen on another port, e.g. 7070?

Comment: How is your server exposed to the internet? Behind a NAT router, or is the public IP connected directly to your server?

Comment: Duplicate of [Apache server not broadcasting to internet](http://serverfault.com/questions/175738/apache-server-not-broadcasting-to-internet)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure the port is forwarded if you are behind NAT (ie, if your ip is 192.168.x.x or similar). Since you likely have a dynamic ip (even if it doesn't seem to change a lot, if it is issued via DHCP it is dynamic), you should consider a service like dyndns.org. Also, it is very likely that hosting a server is against your ISPs terms of service and could get your account suspended. Your ISP pay also be blocking port 80, preventing anyone from accessing your apache server. You might consider changing the Listen port and seeing if that makes a difference.

Comment: I see a lot of ISPs blocking :80 at their level, stopping anyone from getting through at all.

Comment: Well, that is how they sell the 'business' class packages, actually static IPs and port 25 and 80 open properly. ISPs charging you to not interfere with your packets, what fun.